# Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

So I need to make a specific hashcode function that meets a specific algorithm. The algorithm isn't really important in the context of this question. I'm getting a seg fault and am not sure how to fix it. I debugged it in gdb and found out it's from accessing an invalid memory address.

here's my code:

```
int hash_code(const char* str){
   int len = strlen(str);
   char* dst;
   if(len == 0 )
   return 0;
 else{
   strncpy(dst, str, (len - 1));
   return (hash_code(dst) * 65599) + str[len-1];
  }
}
```

I'm pretty confident that it's from the dst, but I'm not sure how to work around it, to not get the seg fault. What would I use or initialize dst with to avoid this?

Comment: `strncpy(dst, str, (len - 1));` `dst` isn't initialize. `dst` pointed  memory is not ensured.

Comment: Do you know which line you're getting the seg fault on? There are several possibilities, including the line @BLUEPIXY pointed out as most likely

Comment: @BLUEPIXY so how should i initialize dst?

Comment: @Chris it's from the strncpy line which I assume is a result of dst

Comment: `char *dst = calloc(len); .. memcpy(dst, str, len - 1);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strncpy` does not null-terminate its output if the buffer is too small. For this reason, many people consider it a poor choice of function in almost all circumstances.

Your code has another problem in that `dst` does not point anywhere, but you try to write characters through it. Where do you imagine those characters are going? Likely this causes your segfault, trying to write characters to a random memory location that you have not allocated.

Assuming you want to stick with the recursive approach: Instead of making a copy of the string every time, change your function to pass the length of the string. Then you don't need to allocate any memory, nor waste any time calling `strlen`:

```
unsigned int hash_code(const char *str, size_t len)
{
    if ( len == 0 )
        return 0;

    return hash_code(str, len - 1) * 65599 + str[len - 1];
}
```

Note - to avoid integer overflow problems, use an unsigned type for the hash value.